# Stationary Distributions and Financial Markets

Tags: model, stationarity, markov-process, finance

Not sure my idea makes sense but here goes. Financial markets are notoriously hard to model. Is this perhaps there does not exist a stationary distribution for any Markov chain stochastic process modelling any given financial security's prices, and hence we cannot reasonably compute statistics that are adequate for future predictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up a few concepts here. Precisely because some processes are thought of as Markov chains, they are impossible to predict. Consider a random variable $x_t\sim N(\mu_t,\sigma^2_t)$. Even if you know $\mu_t,\sigma_t$ at time $s<t$, you cannot predict $x_t$. However, in financial markets you often don't need to predict $x_t$, it is enough to know $\mu_t,\sigma_t$ to profit. In other words, to make money it is sufficient to be able to know what is the distribution. The problem is that we rarely know the distribution.

Another thing is the microstructure of markets vs idealized perfect markets. The latter at best realize only in pockets of markets, e.g. trading on highly liquid securities such as AAPL or Treasury bonds can be quite efficient, and you end up with some Markov processes. The large swaths of the markets are very illiquid, and there's a lot of opportunity (or at least promise) to predict the prices, for instance.

Comment: This is an awesome answer, thank you! My additioanl question is "why do we rarely know the distribution"? This is a really hard question to answer I think, and harder than my original question/thought. Cheer